# EF5 CF - updating attached object

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How can I update (replace) object that was attached to EF DbContext already?

There is the Update() method in DAL:

```cs
public int Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    this._context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
    this._context.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

at some point it can receive 2 or more **different** instances of TEntity with same key value (simple example, not from real project):

```cs
var e1 = new SomeEntity() { Id = 1; }
dal.Update(e1);
...    
var e2 = new SomeEntity() { Id = 1; }
dal.Update(e2); 
// Exception: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. 
...
dal.Commit();
```

I need to save old last value (e2). How can I do it (without create new context for second update)?

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you to solve your problem, please consider marking it as "Accepted" by clicking the little checkbox below its score. If not, please provide us more details on what isn't working so we can help you further.

Answer (score 5):

Just thought I'd add this to the mix, since I came across this post - and used the solution Ladislav suggested, with a few changes:

```
public T Save<T>(T entity) where T : class {
    try {
        this.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    } catch { 
      // You may wish to add logging here, instead of throwing away the exception
    }

    try {
        this.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.SaveChanges();
        this.Entry<T>(entity).Reload(); // Update any server-generated fields
        this.Detach<T>(entity); // Detach the object again, to avoid collisions
    } catch { return null; }

    return entity; // Return the updated version of the object.
}
internal void Detach<T>(T entity) where T : class {
    ObjectContext.Detach(entity);
}

public ObjectContext ObjectContext {
    get { return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext; }
}
```

Let me point out the changes explicitly, and why I made them.

First - there are 2 `try/catch` blocks. The first makes sure that if the object is already attached, we don't error out. You don't actually need to *do* anything with the error - it is informational, rather than critical. So - just ignore it if it happens - and go on.

The second `try/catch` block gracefully handles any other kind of saving error. If your change would violate a foreign-key constraint, for instance - this block will catch the failure.

The third thing is that I added a `Detach<T>()` method. This is to prevent the collision for `.Attach()` as well. Essentially, my assumption is that if you are writing a generic method like this which needs to `.Attach()` objects in the first place - it's because you're using POCOs without change-tracking. That being the case - it makes sense that after you're done saving / updating - you should detach again.

For completeness - I should also point out that if you actually want to explicitly catch the "Object is already attached" error - you should catch `InvalidOperationException` in the first `catch` block.

*An even better approach*

If you *do* have the ability to add a base class or interface (which you should, if you're using `.tt` generated objects), you can improve the type-safety of this solution by replacing the first line as follows:

```
public void Save<T>(T entity) where T : BaseClass {
```

In my application's EF5 `POCO.tt` file, I've altered it to output a base class for every object, as well as added some serialization support, and some other tweaks. The meat of it comes from these lines:

```
/* THIS SECTION ADDED IN ORDER TO CREATE A GLOBAL BASE CLASS */

fileManager.StartNewFile("EntityBase.cs");
#>
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

<# BeginNamespace(code); #>
<# foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection)) { #>
[KnownType(typeof(<#=code.Escape(entity)#>))]
<# } #>
public abstract class EntityBase { }
<#
EndNamespace(code);

/* END INJECTED BASE CLASS */
```

I then also update the `.tt`'s `EntityClassOpening()` function to look like the following:

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity) {
    String baseType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType);
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        _code.Escape(entity),
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseType) ? "EntityBase" : baseType)
    );
}
```

The result is that all of my POCO objects that don't already have inheritance now derive from `EntityBase` - which allows me to change my `Save<T>` signature to:

```
public T Save<T>(T entity) where T : EntityBase {
```

... and now my code is type-safe at compile time.

So - how do you use it effectively?

Remember that the `.Save<T>()` method returns `null` if it fails, and an updated version of the entity if it succeeds. I generally call it as follows:

```
if (null == (entity = db.Save(entity))
    throw new Exception( ... );

// If we got this far, it's because the save succeeded.
DoSomething().With(entity);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : IEntityWithId {
    DbSet<TEntity> set = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    TEntity original = set.Local.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
    if (original != null) {
        _context.Entry<TEntity>(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    } else {
        set.Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

You just need to implement and interface on your entities to support this operation:

```
public interface IEntityWithId {
    int Id { get; }
}
```

Comment: I want to find solution without adding some additional interface like IEntityWithId. And even more - key can be composite (from 2 or more properties) and different for each entity type.

Comment: In such case: a) Don't use generic update method because it is not sufficient for your use case OR b) Update still the same instance of the object to avoid this issue. If you want to find the original object to update its values you must know its key.